# route angular in ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, ionic-view

```
    /**
 *
 * @TODO: Make several files for the controllers if we have so many script
 *
 */

angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ui.router'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
.controller('RegistreCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {


})

.controller('FacturerCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})

.controller('DocumentsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
.controller('ParametresCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {

})
//controller pour connection to API
.controller('LoginConnect', ['$scope','connecting','sendtoken','$state','$stateParams',
function($scope,connecting,sendtoken,$state){

    $scope.user = {};
    var users = $scope.user;
    $scope.connect = function (users,$state) {
      var log = $scope.user.login;
      var pass = $scope.user.password;
      var mydata = {};
      connecting.login(log,pass).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
        var montoken = result.data.token;
         sessionStorage.setItem('token',montoken);
         console.log(montoken);
      });


      var mytoken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
      console.log(mytoken);
       sendtoken.send(mytoken).then(function(userdata){
         $scope.datab = userdata;
          if($scope.datab = userdata){
            $state.go('app.registre');
          };
          // var datauser = sessionStorage.getItem('myuserdata');
          // if (datauser != ''){
          //    $state.transitionTo("app.registre");
          // };
       });



    };



  }

  // function($location){
    // if()
  //   $location.url("/home");
  // }
])
  //factory pour aller chercher le token
.factory('connecting', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
      var ConnectingFactory = {};
      ConnectingFactory.login = function(log,pass){
       var deferred = $q.defer();
       $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/login.php",
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
           transformRequest: function(obj) {
               var str = [];
               for(var p in obj)
               str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
               return str.join("&");
           },
           data: {login: log, password: pass}
           })
       .success(function(result){
          deferred.resolve(result);
          // var promise = deferred.promise;
          // promise.then(function(result){
          // var  mydata = result["data"];
          // console.log(mydata);
          //   }
          //);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
       };
       return ConnectingFactory;

}])
    //END factory pour aller chercher le token

    //Factory pour envoyer le token
    .factory('sendtoken', ['$http','$q', function ($http,$q){
          var tokenreceipt = {};
          tokenreceipt.send = function(mytoken){
           var deferred = $q.defer();
           $http({
               method: 'POST',
               url: "http://api.tiime-ae.fr/0.1/request/settings-get.php",
               headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
               transformRequest: function(obj) {
                   var str = [];
                   for(var p in obj)
                   str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
                   return str.join("&");
               },
               data: {token : mytoken}
               })
               .success(function(userdata){
                  deferred.resolve(userdata);
                  // var promise = deferred.promise;
                  // promise.then(function(result){
                  // var  mydata = result["data"];
                  // console.log(mydata);
                  //   }
                  //);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
               };
               return tokenreceipt;
    }]);
      //END Factory pour envoyer le token
;
```

and my app.js:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
  })
  .state('app.login', {
    cache:false,
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/form-connection.html',
        controller: 'LoginConnect'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.registre', {
    url: '/registre',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/registre.html',
        controller: 'RegistreCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.facturer', {
    url: '/facturer',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/facturer.html',
        controller: 'FacturerCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.documents', {
    url: '/documents',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/documents.html',
        controller: 'DocumentsCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('app.parametres', {
    url: '/parametres',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/parametres.html',
        controller: 'ParametresCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

Hi, here is my problem, i don t know how to change the view only when i retrieve my data. It says : "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined". Because i want that : when my function is success, the path change and send me to the home page. Do you have an idea ? I would really appreciate !

Comment: bro you an use $state if you are using ionic, Is there any specific reason you want to use $location.path

Comment: No but even with $ state it s not working

Comment: in $state you need to give state name not url. If you are doing so please share your js file in which route config is happening and u need to add dependency for $state in your controller

Comment: when i use $state i have this : Cannot read property 'go' of undefined

Comment: bro dependency on your controller $state

Comment: No need to pass $state to $scope.connect function in controller only it's needed

Comment: Done but still not working :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105024/discussion-between-siddharth-pandey-and-guillaume-nouhaud).

Answer (score 0):

You can create you factories in simple way and return promises to controller i think it's controllers job to handle promises.

And this will solve your routing problem also as the success will be the part of controller not of factory

```
factory('AuthHttpSvcs', function($http, $location, $rootScope) {
    return {
        login: function(loginData) {
            //return the promise directly.
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'YOUR_URL',
                data: loginData
            }).then(function(result) {
                //returns object with every detail.
                return result;
            });
        }
    }
});
```